# Redirect category to url with /category

Tags: categories, loop, permalinks, redirect

I'm want to redirect every category page to to URL prepended by `/category`.
For example; I want `/blog` redirecting to /category/blog

Why? For some reason `/blog` gives to same result as `/category/blog`, but if you'll visit /blog the navigation structure doesn't work anymore. The next page of blogs posts will be `/blog/page/2` instead of `/category/blog/page/2`. The first example returns an 404 page.

My permalink structure is set to `/%category%/%postname%/` and on the permalink page I've set the categorybase to 'categorie', Dutch for category (so read every category above as categorie haha).

Somewhere on the internet I did found the following piece of code. Unfortunately this code leads to a redirect loop:

```
add_filter('term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3);
function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( is_category( 'blog' ) ) {
        $url = site_url( '/categorie/blog' );
        wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
        exit;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Hopefully someone will know a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working correctly but the logic of the code is wrong. You are doing this: if we are in "blog" category, redirect to "blog" category. So, if you go to blog category you will be redirected forever. You should think carefully about what `/blog` url is and make the proper checking.

Anyway, when dealing with 301 redirections, I prefer to try .htaccess first. If it can be done through .htaccess, do it; you will save server resources because the redirection occurs before any PHP code is loaded.

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog(.*)$ http://example.com/category/blog$1
```

The above code does this: if the url start with `/blog(any-string-here)`, redirect to `/category/blog(any-string-here)` with 301 HTTP status code.

If you want to catch exactly `/blog` to `/category/blog`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog$ http://example.com/category/blog
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I've tried to manage it using .htaccess but it didn't seem to work. After that I did contact my hosting, so I'll have to wait for there action.